# Jazz RTC - How to create a snapshot or a baseline for numerous streams

Tags: snapshot, rtc, ibm-jazz

I am managing 5 apps on the RTC. Each app got its own stream.
I want to create a baseline/snapshot for numerous streams or for source control directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply have to create a dedicated project/stream on which you add 5 baselines, one per applications.

From that stream, you can create a snapshot, which will memorize those 5 applications baselines.